# Simperium with OS X and NSArrayControllers

Tags: macos, cocoa-bindings, simperium

I am currently making an iOS/OS X app that uses simperium to manage syncing. If I follow the instructions for setting up iOS, everything works fine between iOS devices. When setting up on OS X, I've followed the additional setup instructions, but am getting some interesting behavior. The NSLogs from Simperium say that anything I create in the OS X app is being managed by simperium, but they are not showing up in the data browser on simperium's site (thus, no syncing data created in the osx app). For my OS X app, I am using a table view with cocoa bindings. My Core Data entities all inherit properly from SPManagedObject. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Edit: If I print out [self.simperium objectsForEntityName@"Name"], I get the following:

> "SPManagedObject: 0x100245730 (entity: Name; id: 0x1010471d0 x-coredata://F1A16321-32F4-4B4E-93A6-75B8DD6B1B23/Name/p102 ; data: fault)",
>   "SPManagedObject: 0x100255770 (entity: Name; id: 0x10101b990 x-coredata://F1A16321-32F4-4B4E-93A6-75B8DD6B1B23/Name/p103 ; data: fault)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a problem with Entities that were not using a custom subclass. The "iosupdate" branch for [the Simperium repository on GitHub](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium) fixes this problem. This fix will eventually move to the main branch as well.

Note that the log output you pasted looks correct and is expected.

Comment: Thanks again for the help. This worked for me. Sorry I didn't update this sooner.